# code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x88\x80\xa32\xc9\x98')

Tags: python, websocket, novnc

noVNC websocket log shows above message on an authentication event. The authentication is always failing and noVNC is reporting subject error.

Some times the error comes as
**code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x88\x8fR\x80\x19\x98QhM\xf9')**

Is ('\x88\x80\xa32\xc9\x98') an ASCII or UTF-8 ? How to read and understand this message ?

Background :
CentOS 5 / Python 2.4.3 / noVNC

Comment: try to see this https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/issues/422

Comment: Removing path as websockify does not help. The output remains same.

Comment: It seems this can be safely ignored for noVNC case. I was able to get noVNC working despite having this message & this had nothing to do with authentication. Thanks.

Comment: have a look at this post: http://www.arkilis.me/?p=539

Comment: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/1029

Answer (score 3):

For those that stumbled to this page...and you are just running a vanilla tensorboard setup, first verify your url starts with "http://" as oppose to "https://"!

The message below is what i got when i attempted to access tensorboard (http) with https:

`code 400, message Bad request version ('\x1a\x1a\x13\x01\x13 ...`

Answer (score 1):

It seems [this was a bug](https://github.com/novnc/websockify/issues/177) on websockify's side. It is fixed now, but they didn't make a release that includes the fix, so you have to use the master branch if you want to benefit from it.

Alternatively, you could just add the [relevant line from that pull request](https://github.com/novnc/websockify/commit/30942f12d3909fd9bb4302a9d0b0567c7bcd216a) to the file `websockify/websocket.py`.